# How do I map M:N relationship whose otherside is a weak entity?

Tags: entity-relationship, entity-data-model

I'm trying to map my ERD to a relational schema; one trouble I ran into is regarding the `ENROLLS` relationship which is `M:N`. For `M:N` in relational diagram, i know a separate table is made with the `PKS` from both sides. However, my other side is a weak entity.

The table for `ENROLLS` would then be `[Ssn (PK), ? (PK)]`. I don't know what to do; do I just put all the partial keys?

[image: ERD for database.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to my professor, and my way of approaching this is correct. So, the final table would look like [Ssn (PK), Year (PK), Semester (PK), Number (PK)].